# How to define different compileSdkVersion using productFlavors in app build.gradle in android

Tags: android, build.gradle

I want to add define different compile sdk version for each if my product flavour A and B as mentioned below.

```
 productFlavors {
        a{
            compileSdkVersion 29
        }
        b{
           compileSdkVersion 30
        }
    }
```

But its not detecting. Please help me if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can't have different `build.gradle` for product flavors.
However you should be able to condition the `buildscript` and the `compileSdkVersion`.

It is not so clean but you can use something like:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    if (condition) {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0+'
        }
    } else if (condition) {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
        }
    }
}

android {
  def type="Google"

    if (type=="Google") {
        compileSdkVersion 29
    } else if (type=="Amazon") {
        compileSdkVersion 30            
    }
  //...
}
```

Comment: How to add condition as product flavour like if(a) else if(b)

Comment: you can use a property in gradle.properties or a variable in top-level file. Something like type = google|amazon and then if (project.type == "google") {

Comment: project.type is not recognized in app/build.gradle file. can u share the snippet for this

Comment: Yes I got your point my que is how I get the flavour name as "Google" or  "Amazon" dymamically using any grable property or metod. I want to consume current selected flavour as the def value. For ex. def type => current dynamic value of selected flavor. I dont wan to declare it as harcoded string.

Comment: In my description on top it's already defined you can't have different build.gradle for product flavors. However you should be able to condition the buildscript and the compileSdkVersion